# Jensen's Inequality and Functions Inside and Outside the Expected Value

Tags: probability

Do functions outside of where you do Jensen's Inequality affect the direction of the inequality sign?

For example $E(e^{x^TAx}) \ge e^{E(x^TAx)}$ because $x^TAx$ is convex for positive semi-definite A, but is $-log(E(e^{x^TAx})) \ge -log(e^{E(x^TAx)}) = -E(x^TAx)$ also true or does the -log affect the direction of the inequality.

Thus maximizing $-E(x^TAx)$ maximizes  $-log(E(e^{x^TAx}))$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$\log$ is an increasing function, so if you take $\log$ and multiply by $-1$ then it reverses the inequality. If you didn't multiply by $-1$ then the inequality would be in the same direction, since $\log$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to figure out what was wrong with my problem and it turns out I had a sign problem. As a follow-up, if the inside function inside the expected value is instead $ \frac{1}{e^{x^T A x}} $ which is concave, then with Jensen's Inequality, $ E(x^T A x) \le -log(E(\frac{1}{e^{x^T A x}})) $ and thus maximizing the left hand side maximizes the right?